# Shopify: Add additional sections to a specific product page

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to add additional sections to my Shopify product pages. I've already been successful adding the sections, but would now like to show the sections on only specific products pages. Until now they are showing on all product pages.
Can someone help me with that? This is the code I've used:

```
{% if product.title == "The Ocean Mat" %}
    {% section "index-columns" %}
{% endif %}
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot!

Best,
Lasse

Comment: I think you added section only on the specific product template. How many product templates are in the theme?

Comment: if create any section that available and has the same content on which products you choose it. if you want every product to have unique section content, then need to use a unique product template.

Comment: I have one product template (product.liquid) and added the additional section by doing this: {% section "index-columns" %}. I hoped it might be possible to add an "if" code to only apply this code if a certain product is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `contains` when check for string since your title might not match exactly

```
{% if product.title contains "The Ocean Mat" %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

instead of `product.title`, use `product.type`; it is much easier to control. The customer does not see it and it can be control from the product page.

```
{% if product.type contains "mat" %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Brilliant. It worked using the product.type. Thank you!